# Android SQLite Database No such table issue

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am using SQLite Database in my application for normal insertion and fetching purpose. I am facing **No such table issue** while trying to get table row count for the particular table.

**Logcat Error:**

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_name(code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM table_name
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
       at com.takeoffandroid.database.DBAccess.getCount(SourceFile:384)
       at   com.takeoffandroid.database.DBAccess.isTableCountLogic(SourceFile:402)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

**SQLite create Table query:**

```
private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
private static final String INTEGER_PRIMARY_KEY = " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT";


public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";

private static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";

private static final String COLUMN_URL = "url";
private static final String COLUMN_JSON = "json";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            COLUMN_ID + INTEGER_PRIMARY_KEY + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_URL + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_JSON + TEXT_TYPE + ")";



public static DBAccess init(Context context) {


        if (mInstance == null)
            synchronized (DBAccess.class) {
                if (mInstance == null) {
                    mInstance = new DBAccess(context);

                }
            }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public DBAccess(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
    }
```

**Method to get table row count:**

```
 public  int getCount() {


        int count=0;
        SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        count = cursor.getCount();

        CLog.i("Table count", "Table count size is "+String.valueOf(count));

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        close();

        return count;

    }
```

Please help me if there is any issue in my code, I am completely stucK up with this issue since long time and I couldn't find the solution. Any kinda suggestions would be helpful to me.

**Note:** This is a very random issue which is happening only with few devices.

Comment: Where did you call `DBAccess.init()`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am calling this in the MainActivity.java

Comment: Try to increase `DATABASE_VERSION` or wipe application data.

Comment: I did that as well.

Comment: @Rotwang They are defined in the question

Comment: If you uninstalled your app and re-run it, then it's a caching problem. Re-start your emulator.

Comment: you're saying that this code works in some devices ?